# how to copy what is written in a notepad

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need some Python code, which goes into a txt, takes an email and copies it.
The email will look like this in the txt:

```
Email: teste1@gmail.com
password: teste1
```

just the email,
would help me a lot because I'm racking my brain here
#selenium webdriver

I want to copy the email from a txt to paste into a website to automatically login part of the login I know, the problem is getting the email from the txt

and the txt I say is a notepad

Comment: What does this have to do with Selenium?  Where does the text comes from?

Comment: I want to copy the email from a txt to paste into a website to automatically login part of the login I know, the problem is getting the email from the txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a whole lot to go off here so I don't feel like writing anything. If you specify what you want more I can help. However, please look this over in the meantime:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp

I hope this helps. There are better ways of doing it but I don't know what level of Python you're at, so I will try to keep it simple.

```
with open(r"Downloads\test.txt", "r") as txt_reader:
    found_email = "Not Found"
    
    for line in txt_reader:
        if "email" in line.lower():
            #Breaks line into a list of words seperated by ':' Choses the 2nd word and removes blank spaces        
            found_email = line.split(":")[1].strip()

    print(found_email)
```

Here is the txt file:

```
Email: testemail@gmail.com

Password: pas5w0rd!
```

Comment: I want to copy the email from a txt to paste into a website to automatically login part of the login I know, the problem is getting the email from the txt

and the txt I say is a notepad

Comment: @GusxtavoLM Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @GusxtavoLM Instead of reading from a txt file you could use a Python dictionary  or JSON. Check out my repo using selenium as an example: https://github.com/GrilledLambda/NeweggAutoPurchaseBot/blob/main/Code/BotSettings.py

Comment: about the copy of testemail@gmail.com? for example, the 'c' control

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to do this try this.First create python file

```
from optparse import OptionParser
import os.path
import re

regex = re.compile(("([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`"
                    "{|}~-]+)*(@|\sat\s)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.|"
                    "\sdot\s))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)"))

def file_to_str(filename):
    """Returns the contents of filename as a string."""
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read().lower() # Case is lowered to prevent regex mismatches.

def get_emails(s):
    """Returns an iterator of matched emails found in string s."""
    # Removing lines that start with '//' because the regular expression
    # mistakenly matches patterns like 'http://foo@bar.com' as '//foo@bar.com'.
    return (email[0] for email in re.findall(regex, s) if not email[0].startswith('//'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = OptionParser(usage="Usage: python %prog [FILE]...")
    # No options added yet. Add them here if you ever need them.
    options, args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args:
        parser.print_usage()
        exit(1)

    for arg in args:
        if os.path.isfile(arg):
            for email in get_emails(file_to_str(arg)):
                print(email)
        else:
            print('"{}" is not a file.'.format(arg))
            parser.print_usage()
```

I can recommend this.because this work for me.

Comment: could explain a little more about the code, i still don't understand the function

Comment: This just seems like an overly complicated version of what I made. Maybe you could help use understand why you would want to use this version?

Comment: @GusxtavoLM first you have to save this file name as you want                                
 ex: emailextract.py . After that create a file with text file with emails and add file name with txt extention . Then run the program like this python yourpythonfilename text file name      ex:    emailextract.py text.txt       and hit enter          If you want I would like zoom meeting